# restart thread when it is therminated

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I m working on an android app who should send data to Server every 3 secondes ,and give a hand to user to start or stop this process ,
So I created a thread like this :

```
class updaterunner implements Runnable {
        // @Override
        public void run() {
            while (threadex) {
                try {
                    doWork();
                    Thread.sleep(30000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }

        public void doWork() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    new startasynch().execute();

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

`thradex` is initialised as false

The start button is calling this function :

```
threadex = true;

if (myThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
{
    myThread.start();
}
```

And the Stop Button is calling this :

```
threadex = false;
```

The first start works well , Stop works well , but when I tried to restart it it doesnt work , and when I checked the thread status , i found it TERMINATED .. Can some explain me this please ?

Comment: What doesn't work exactly. if you do nothing and don't click stop button. does it work every 30 sec.

Comment: The code in the `run` method reached the end when `threadex` was set to `false`.  So the thread terminated.  Were you expecting that it would magically reset itself back to `NEW` even though it isn't new?

Comment: So you are creating a thread, which sole purpose is to go back to the ui thread and start an async task from there...!?

Comment: @hasan83 .. Yes if I dont click on Stop Button it works

Comment: @ajb : I'm wanna know how could i restart it

Comment: Once the thread object reaches the end of its code, you can't restart the same object.  Either create a new object (`myThread = new [something...]`), or redo the logic of your `updaterunner` so that after `threadex` becomes false and the loop exits, it loops back and waits for a signal from another thread to continue again.  You can do this with `wait` and `notify` on some other object, but there are probably better ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (big-T) Thread object manages the life-cycle of a (little t) thread.  A (little t) thread is not a thing that can be "re-started".  Those words don't mean anything:  A little-t thread comes into existence when you call myThread.start(), and it ceases to exist when its run() method returns.  You can't re-start something that no longer exists.

The Java library developers designed the big-T Thread class to reflect that way of thinking about threads.  If you want to create a new little-t thread (even if it's going to do exactly what the old one did), you must create a new big-T Thread to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

I think a much easier solution for you would be to use Androids **AsyncTask**. It will do your work asynchronous, and provide you all the callbacks you need, to keep your UI thread free. It would look something like this:

```
package com.example.asynctasktest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MyAsyncTask backgroundTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onButtonPressStopThread(View v){
        backgroundTask.cancel(false);
    }

    public void onButtonPressStartThread(View v){
        startThread();
    }

    public void startThread(){
        backgroundTask = new MyAsyncTask();
        backgroundTask.execute();
    }

    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Send data to server

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            startThread();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added button clicks for starting and stopping the thread execution.